# RecyclerView not updating correctly

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

Am I using RecyclerView correctly? Whenever I update the data, the is one moment in which the view still displays the old data, despite having modified the dataset and having called the relevant `notify` method. On top of that, I don't see any animations, so I must be doing something wrong.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
private void refreshData() {
    Utils.hideSoftKeyboard(this);
    if (!Utils.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.toast_no_conn, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    String stopNumber = mStopEdit.getText().toString();
    if (stopNumber.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.toast_no_stop, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    mResultNoStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mResults.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (!mDataset.isEmpty()) {
        int size = mDataset.size();
        mDataset.clear();
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }
    FiveT.getStopData(stopNumber, mRequestQueue, new FiveT.StopDataClientListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ApiResult result) {
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (result.getStopResults().size() == 0) {
                mResultNoStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.toast_no_data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            int i = 0;
            mStopName.setText(result.getStopName());
            for (StopResult res : result.getStopResults()) {
                mDataset.add(res);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(i++);
            }
            mResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: I initialize the `RecyclerView` like this:

```
mDataset = new ArrayList<StopResult>();
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.results_recycler_view);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mDataset, getApplicationContext());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you do al the binding of mDataset in your adapter class?

Comment: @urudroid Yes, I modify the layout of the view only in the method `onBindViewHolder` of the adapter (and only through the view holder).

Comment: can you provide the initialisation of your recyclerview? make sure you're setting a [item animator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setItemAnimator(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator))

Comment: @urudroid Ah, I forgot about that. I'm not setting any animator. I edited the post though. Now I'll look that up.

Comment: you can use [this](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) as reference

Comment: @urudroid Thanks, it is very easy to integrate that into my project!

Comment: did you have any progress on this issue?

Comment: @urudroid Thanks to your help now the view seems to update properly. If you want to elaborate your comments into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question's comments:

What you're missing there, in RecyclerView's initialisation, is the set of a item animator.

According to your code:

```
mDataset = new ArrayList<StopResult>();

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.results_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new MyItemAnimator());

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mDataset, getApplicationContext());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) library in order to find an animation that it is best for your needs.